# Average diamonds Price by Clarity lower for diamonds with higher clarity

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been trying to understand why do I get lower average price for diamonds with higher clarity? Aren't diamonds with higher clarity more expensive? Can anyone explain it to me on basic data science level?

Thank you!

```
   by_clarity <- diamonds %>%
      group_by(clarity) %>%
      summarise(
        n = n(), 
        mean = mean(price), 
        lq = quantile(price, 0.25), 
        uq = quantile(price, 0.75)
      )
    by_clarity
    #> Source: local data frame [8 x 5]
    #> 
    #>    clarity     n  mean    lq    uq
    #>     (fctr) (int) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
    #> 1       I1   741  3924  2080  5161
    #> 2      SI2  9194  5063  2264  5777
    #> 3      SI1 13065  3996  1089  5250
    #> 4      VS2 12258  3925   900  6024
    #> 5      VS1  8171  3839   876  6023
    #> 6     VVS2  5066  3284   794  3638
    #> ..     ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
    ggplot(by_clarity, aes(clarity, mean)) + 
      geom_linerange(aes(ymin = lq, ymax = uq)) + 
      geom_line(aes(group = 1), colour = "grey50") +
      geom_point(aes(size = n))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Price is determined by more than one component - including clarity but especially carat weight. One way to view the data is

```
dia<-diamonds

ggplot(data=dia, aes(x=carat, y=price, color=clarity, size=carat)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Toward the bottom left we see high clarity lower carat diamonds at a lower price than top middle moderate clarity larger carat diamonds.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me a great deal in completely understanding this!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of seeing what user @John Walker said is to group by `clarity` and `carat`. And then graph the result.

```
by_clarity_carat <- diamonds %>%
      group_by(clarity, carat) %>%
      summarise(
        n = n(), 
        mean = mean(price),
        lq = quantile(price, 0.25), 
        uq = quantile(price, 0.75)
      )

ggplot(by_clarity_carat, aes(carat, mean)) + 
      geom_linerange(aes(ymin = lq, ymax = uq)) + 
      geom_line(aes(group = 1), colour = "grey50") +
      geom_point(aes(size = n)) + 
      facet_wrap(~ clarity)
```

[image]

As you can see, there are diamonds of less clarity and more carats reaching high prices but though there are no large diamonds of more clarity, these diamonds go up to not more than the middle of the carat scale, the better clarities also reach high prices.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me a great deal in completely understanding this!